# Wordpress action help for post.php?action=edit

Tags: wordpress, action

Question for you regarding wordpress.

I want to display a notification at the top of post.php?action=edit if the get_post_meta is a certain value... any advice how I can more effectively accomplish this? I seem to be getting no response from this code.

```
add_action('admin_notices', 'HMMultipostMU_notifyChild' );

if( !function_exists( 'HMMultipostMU_notifyChild' ) ){
function HMMultipostMU_notifyChild(){
    global $hmMultipostMU;
    if( !isset( $hmMultipostMU ) ){
        return;     
    }

    if($meta = get_post_meta($post_id, 'HMMultipostMU_parent', true)) {
        $parent = unserialize( $meta );
        if(!empty($parent)) {
            foreach ($parent as $key => $value) {
                switch_to_blog( $key );
                echo '<div id="message" class="updated highlight"> WARNING: This is a child article! Please <a href='. get_edit_post_link( $value ). '>click here</a> to edit this article as the Parent. Be Aware, this may switch blog sites.<br /> </div>';
            }
            restore_current_blog();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Remember that there is also wordpress.stackexchange.com, where all they do is walk about WP-oriented stuff.

Comment: Did you try to echo the `$meta` and see if it is getting a return for that variable?

Comment: I found my issue! ahhh. $post_id wasn't defined until the page runs... I had to change it to $_GET var. Gr sorry thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue! ahhh. $post_id wasn't defined until the page runs... I had to change it to $_GET var. Gr sorry thanks!